# Spring Security LDAP Authentication only: PartialResultsException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, ldap

I am using:
spring-boot 1.0.2.RELEASE
spring-security-ldap: 3.2.4.RELEASE

I am trying to authenticate users with our AD server. I do not want to load roles, this will be handled locally. Here is my security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("<my-domain>", "ldap://<my-server>:389");
    provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
    auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
}
```

Inspecting in wireshark shows the following:

```
LDAP  bindRequest(1) "<user>@<my-domain>" simple
LDAP  bindResponse(1) success
LDAP  searchRequest(2) "dc=<my-domain>" wholesubtree
LDAP  searchResDone(2) referral
LDAP unbindRequest(3)
```

I can see that the bind request is succeeding, it is the directory search that is failing (getting referred). As far as I am concerned, this is a success, and I do not care about the searchRequest. Is there any way to skip this step and perform only the bind?

I have tried a variety of things, all without success. Many solutions seem to be to specify a more accurate DN, or follow referals. I do not know what the DN should be, and cannot install any tools to discover this (if there are any other ways please let me know!). I have read that following referals can slow it down somewhat, I am wondering If I can simply skip this step and treat the authentication as successful

Thanks!